# android can't disable bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Bluebooth is used for a long time, it's can't use. When I disable the bluetooth, after a period of time, it Automatically open.
Error Print information:

```
05-05 06:28:25.814: E/BTIF_CORE(5554): btif_disable_bluetooth : not yet enabled
05-05 06:28:33.819: E/BluetoothAdapterState(5554): Error disabling Bluetooth
05-05 06:28:33.855: E/PRX(628): hard code service registered.
05-05 06:28:33.874: E/BluetoothServiceJni(5554): SOCK FLAG = 1 ***********************
05-05 06:28:33.874: E/(5554): btmtk_jsr82_session_service_registration@264:[JSR82][JBT] JSR82 does not init
05-05 06:28:33.874: E/BluetoothServiceJni(5554): Socket listen failed: 1
05-05 06:28:33.874: E/BluetoothAdapterService(1112665360)(5554): Failed to create socket channel
05-05 06:28:33.874: E/[MAP]BluetoothMapService(5554): [initSocket] Error create RfcommServerSocket java.io.IOException: Error: -1
05-05 06:28:33.922: E/BluetoothServiceJni(5554): SOCK FLAG = 1 ***********************
05-05 06:28:33.922: E/(5554): btmtk_jsr82_session_service_registration@264:[JSR82][JBT] JSR82 does not init
05-05 06:28:33.922: E/BluetoothServiceJni(5554): Socket listen failed: 1
05-05 06:28:33.923: E/BluetoothAdapterService(1112665360)(5554): Failed to create socket channel
05-05 06:28:33.923: E/BluetoothPbapService(5554): Error create RfcommServerSocket java.io.IOException: Error: -1
05-05 06:28:33.982: E/BluetoothReceiver(1042): [MMI][BluetoothReceiver.startService][start service [com.mediatek.bluetooth.AdvancedService]
05-05 06:28:33.994: E/BluetoothServiceJni(5554): SOCK FLAG = 0 ***********************
05-05 06:28:33.994: E/(5554): btmtk_jsr82_session_service_registration@264:[JSR82][JBT] JSR82 does not init
```

Comment: do you turn off bluetooth from within an app you made? if so please post code, if your problem just happens in your device regardless of the app then this question is not programming related

Comment: @Dengshun Yin : Please post your code.

Comment: don't turn of in my app.but this problem is app run after a period of time.bluetooth continue to restart in app.

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter to =  bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
isServiceRestart = true;
if(to.isEnabled()) {
    to.disable();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    to.enable();
} else if(!to.isEnabled()) {
    to.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80430

Very annoying. Star the issue so Google fix it.